# PropertyGrid AutoSelect Property Value

Tags: c#, visual-studio

We use a [PropertyGrid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302326.aspx) to store information about various GUI controls.

Currently, after dropping a new control onto the form, we next click the [PropertyGrid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302326.aspx), scroll to the field called **Value** and enter the value that will be displayed for that item.

I can handle the part where the [PropertyGrid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302326.aspx) gets focus, and I can even cast the [SelectedObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.propertygrid.selectedobject.aspx) back to our base **GuiControl** object.

Obviously, **Value** is a public property of our **GuiControl** class.

I don't see a way to find the **Value** property on the [PropertyGrid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302326.aspx) and set it to focus to receive text input.

The goal is to drop a control onto the form, have the [PropertyGrid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302326.aspx) get focus, place the Cursor's Caret on the **Value** line, and then we can supply our input.

Is that possible? If so, please give me some idea on how to do that.

Comment: Think of Hot Keys. &F to select the File menu; &T to select Tools, etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set selected item of property grid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24571817/how-to-set-selected-item-of-property-grid)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looping through the GridItems collection to find the Label that matches your property:

```
foreach (GridItem gi in propertyGrid1.SelectedGridItem.Parent.GridItems) {
  if (gi.Label == "Value") {
    propertyGrid1.Select();
    gi.Select();
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah! That did it. Of course now I see that I can't actually write to `gi.Value` because it is read only.