# .net Windows forms Property Grid

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, .net-5

I have a .NET windows forms property grid which is tied to the collection of entities

```
public class Entity
{

public string A { get; set; }
public string B { get; set; }
public string C { get; set; }
}
```

It has a collectioneditor derived from CollectionEditor and attached to entities collection.  The collection Editor works perfectly well when invoked from the property grid .

```
[Editor(typeof(EntityCollectionEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]
    public EntityCollection Entities
    {
        get { return entityCollection; }
    }
```

How can i invoke the propertygrid's instance Collection Editor on the click of a toolbar button ?

The propertygrid instance is EntityPropertyGrid.

Answer (score 0):

> How can i invoke the propertygrid's instance Collection Editor on the click of a toolbar button ?

By this, I assume you mean you want the `PropertyGrid` to give focus to the propert-grid row for your `Entities` property, which should activate or open the editor.

Surprisingly this is not trivial because `PropertyGrid` does not give you a straightforward way to enumerate all rows in the grid... or any of the grid-items except the currently selected row.

[Fortunately you can do it by traversing the object-graph from `SelectedGridItem`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24571817/how-to-set-selected-item-of-property-grid):

Something like this:

```cs
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

// ...

void GiveFocusToEntitiesRow( PropertyGrid g )
{
    GridItem rootItem;
    {
        GridItem arbitrary = g.SelectedGridItem;
        while( arbitrary.Parent != null ) arbitrary.Parent;

        rootItem = arbitrary;
    }

    GridItem entitiesPropertyItem = EnumerateAllItems( rootItem )
        .First( item => item.PropertyDescriptor.Name == nameof(SomethingOrOther.Entities) );

    g.Focus();
    entitiesPropertyItem.Select();
    SendKeys.SendWait("{F4}"); // Enter edit mode
}

private static IEnumerable<GridItem> EnumerateAllItems( GridItem item )
{
    yield return item;
    
    foreach( GridItem child in item.GridItems )
    {
        foreach( GridItem grandChild in EnumerateAllItems( item: child ) )
        {
            yield return grandChild;
        }
    }
}
```

(I appreciate having two levels of `foreach` in `EnumerateAllItems` is a tad confusing, but it's an unfortunate a consequence of how C# lazy enumerators work).

Comment: Thanks Dai for the reply. It doesnt matter if a particular row is selected or not in the property grid. But invoke the collection editor with all the collection data , where the user can add/edit the data.